# Data Refresh Error after upgrade PowerPivot from 2008R2 to 2012

Tags: upgrade, powerpivot

after upgrading PowerPivot for SharePoint I cannot refresh the data in all the workbooks. Error appears when opening a workbook in the gallery or in the Scheduled-Data-Refresh.

**1. Gallery / SharePoint Integrated**
"There was an error....blah blah blah"
and in the Windows Event Log:
"Activation context generation failed for "\Program Files\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\110\msolap110.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ChannelTransport,processorArchitecture="MSIL",publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91",version="11.0.0.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."

**2. Scheduled Data Refresh**
"Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlSerializationException: Deserialization failed: The 'FormatString' element in the 'htt://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300' namespace is unexpected. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlSerializationException: The 'FormatString' element in the 'htt://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300' namespace is unexpected.     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DesignXmlReader.ReadStructContent(Object obj, StructMapping mapping)     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DesignXmlReader.ReadObjectContent(Object value, Type type, TypeMapping mapping)     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DesignXmlReader.ReadClassObject(Type type, MemberMapping mm)     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DesignXmlReader.ReadArrayContent(Object array, Array..."

**3. Installation Files**
I cannot start the SQL Server PowerPivot Configuration Tool (via Installation Center), it is greyed out! But the Version of my PowerPivot Instance is 11.XXXX!

It seems that the "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SharePoint.Integration" dll files in the Windows-Assembly folder were not updated as they still show the version 10.0.0.0!

**What I've done:**

I followed this instruction:
htt://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210646(v=sql.110).aspx
The only thing is: It says I need to install CummUpdate for August 2010 even after I installed SP1 for SharePoint! That is not possible as the built for SP1 is higher than the Aug2010CummUpdate...

Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot